# Apache WAMP Stopped Working

Tags: apache, localhost, wamp, wampserver

I was enabling something in my WAMP. Anyhow I clicked on the Wamp Button > Apache > Apache Modules > and I was looking for what I wanted, but accidentally pressed "r". Once I pressed "r" my localhost website would not work, and now my Wamp icon is appearing orange. I have no clue what happend, do you? Here is my error:

```
[Sat Jul 26 16:15:29.537732 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4092:tid 400] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Jul 26 16:15:29.537732 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4092:tid 400] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Sat Jul 26 16:15:29.537732 2014] [core:notice] [pid 4092:tid 400] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Sat Jul 26 16:15:29.538734 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4092:tid 400] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 1608
[Sat Jul 26 16:15:30.029179 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1608:tid 452] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Sat Jul 26 22:33:53.434220 2014] [authz_core:error] [pid 1608:tid 960] [client 192.168.1.30:54781] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/www/
[Sat Jul 26 22:51:56.233745 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4092:tid 400] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Sat Jul 26 22:51:58.265082 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1608:tid 452] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Sat Jul 26 22:51:58.296328 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4092:tid 400] AH00430: Parent: Child process 1608 exited successfully.
[Sun Jul 27 14:05:56.746487 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5232:tid 284] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jul 27 14:05:56.753499 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5232:tid 284] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Sun Jul 27 14:05:56.753499 2014] [core:notice] [pid 5232:tid 284] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Sun Jul 27 14:05:56.763491 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5232:tid 284] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6916
[Sun Jul 27 14:05:57.485065 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6916:tid 460] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Jul 30 23:20:46.242815 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5232:tid 284] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Wed Jul 30 23:20:51.539762 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6916:tid 460] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Wed Jul 30 23:21:05.180559 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5232:tid 284] AH00430: Parent: Child process 6916 exited successfully.
[Thu Jul 31 12:45:25.093273 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2568:tid 536] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jul 31 12:45:25.094274 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2568:tid 536] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Thu Jul 31 12:45:25.094274 2014] [core:notice] [pid 2568:tid 536] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Thu Jul 31 12:45:25.097276 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2568:tid 536] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2596
[Thu Jul 31 12:45:26.045952 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2596:tid 424] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Tue Aug 19 16:05:08.423733 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2568:tid 536] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Tue Aug 19 16:05:13.642604 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2596:tid 424] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Tue Aug 19 16:05:30.064645 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2568:tid 536] AH00430: Parent: Child process 2596 exited successfully.
[Tue Aug 19 23:30:25.524220 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5720:tid 572] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Aug 19 23:30:25.553224 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5720:tid 572] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Tue Aug 19 23:30:25.553224 2014] [core:notice] [pid 5720:tid 572] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Tue Aug 19 23:30:25.556224 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5720:tid 572] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2012
[Tue Aug 19 23:30:26.184670 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2012:tid 452] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Aug 27 10:43:18.752095 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5720:tid 572] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Wed Aug 27 10:43:21.845885 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2012:tid 452] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Wed Aug 27 10:43:28.517847 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5720:tid 572] AH00430: Parent: Child process 2012 exited successfully.
[Thu Aug 28 17:22:50.302524 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3476:tid 528] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Aug 28 17:22:50.303536 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3476:tid 528] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Thu Aug 28 17:22:50.303536 2014] [core:notice] [pid 3476:tid 528] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Thu Aug 28 17:22:50.305520 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3476:tid 528] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2632
[Thu Aug 28 17:22:51.240439 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2632:tid 448] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Tue Sep 02 20:02:08.448199 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3476:tid 528] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Tue Sep 02 20:02:10.495104 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2632:tid 448] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Tue Sep 02 20:02:12.604507 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3476:tid 528] AH00430: Parent: Child process 2632 exited successfully.
[Fri Sep 05 21:55:31.379470 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6080:tid 488] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Sep 05 21:55:31.402538 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6080:tid 488] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Fri Sep 05 21:55:31.402538 2014] [core:notice] [pid 6080:tid 488] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Fri Sep 05 21:55:31.404485 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6080:tid 488] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3256
[Fri Sep 05 21:55:32.012043 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3256:tid 448] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Sun Sep 14 20:08:13.490202 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6080:tid 488] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Sun Sep 14 20:08:17.209027 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3256:tid 448] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Sun Sep 14 20:08:23.584115 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6080:tid 488] AH00430: Parent: Child process 3256 exited successfully.
[Fri Sep 19 20:55:13.884326 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8340:tid 556] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Sep 19 20:55:13.884326 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8340:tid 556] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Fri Sep 19 20:55:13.884326 2014] [core:notice] [pid 8340:tid 556] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Fri Sep 19 20:55:13.888323 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8340:tid 556] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 8116
[Fri Sep 19 20:55:14.532934 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8116:tid 452] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Sat Sep 20 19:54:01.953621 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8340:tid 556] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Sat Sep 20 19:54:03.984898 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8116:tid 452] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Sat Sep 20 19:54:05.984928 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8340:tid 556] AH00430: Parent: Child process 8116 exited successfully.
[Mon Nov 03 17:15:38.006650 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6552:tid 532] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Nov 03 17:15:38.022297 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6552:tid 532] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Mon Nov 03 17:15:38.022297 2014] [core:notice] [pid 6552:tid 532] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Mon Nov 03 17:15:38.022297 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6552:tid 532] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4616
[Mon Nov 03 17:15:38.709800 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4616:tid 448] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Mon Nov 17 20:07:44.422884 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6552:tid 532] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Mon Nov 17 20:07:46.516716 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4616:tid 448] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Mon Nov 17 20:07:58.048122 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6552:tid 532] AH00430: Parent: Child process 4616 exited successfully.
[Sat Nov 22 15:49:46.091430 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2112:tid 528] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Nov 22 15:49:46.092432 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2112:tid 528] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Sat Nov 22 15:49:46.092432 2014] [core:notice] [pid 2112:tid 528] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Sat Nov 22 15:49:46.097436 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2112:tid 528] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4212
[Sat Nov 22 15:49:46.818947 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4212:tid 460] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Sun Nov 23 17:27:17.509537 2014] [:error] [pid 4212:tid 968] [client ::1:55412] script 'C:/wamp/www/testwebsite/action.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://localhost/testwebsite/home.php
[Sun Nov 23 18:24:20.050683 2014] [:error] [pid 4212:tid 968] [client ::1:55774] script 'C:/wamp/www/testwebsite/action.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://localhost/testwebsite/home.php
[Tue Nov 25 23:41:55.578131 2014] [authz_core:error] [pid 4212:tid 956] [client ::1:57231] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/Apache24, referer: http://localhost/postin%27/
[Tue Nov 25 23:41:55.579129 2014] [authz_core:error] [pid 4212:tid 956] [client ::1:57231] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/Apache24, referer: http://localhost/postin%27/
[Tue Nov 25 23:41:55.582134 2014] [authz_core:error] [pid 4212:tid 960] [client ::1:57233] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/Apache24, referer: http://localhost/postin%27/
[Tue Nov 25 23:41:55.583131 2014] [authz_core:error] [pid 4212:tid 948] [client ::1:57234] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/Apache24, referer: http://localhost/postin%27/
[Tue Nov 25 23:41:55.584132 2014] [authz_core:error] [pid 4212:tid 968] [client ::1:57235] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/Apache24, referer: http://localhost/postin%27/
[Fri Nov 28 17:08:26.648100 2014] [:error] [pid 4212:tid 960] [client ::1:57746] script 'C:/wamp/www/postin'/home.php' not found or unable to stat
[Fri Nov 28 17:11:46.907963 2014] [:error] [pid 4212:tid 960] [client ::1:57777] script 'C:/wamp/www/postin'/bootstrap-3.3.1-dist/dist/home.php' not found or unable to stat
[Fri Nov 28 17:15:44.406860 2014] [core:error] [pid 4212:tid 944] (20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: [client ::1:57972] AH00127: Cannot map GET /postin%27/%3C!--%20bootstrap-3.3.1-dist/dist/css/%20--%3Ebootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1 to file, referer: http://localhost/postin%27/home.php
[Fri Nov 28 17:18:10.663503 2014] [:error] [pid 4212:tid 948] [client ::1:58026] script 'C:/wamp/www/postin'/bootstrap-3.3.1-dist/dist/home.php' not found or unable to stat
[Fri Nov 28 17:18:12.207563 2014] [:error] [pid 4212:tid 948] [client ::1:58026] script 'C:/wamp/www/postin'/bootstrap-3.3.1-dist/dist/home.php' not found or unable to stat
[Fri Dec 05 18:24:55.774622 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2112:tid 528] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Fri Dec 05 18:24:59.102790 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4212:tid 460] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Fri Dec 05 18:25:05.634129 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2112:tid 528] AH00430: Parent: Child process 4212 exited successfully.
[Fri Dec 05 18:31:26.578880 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5104:tid 524] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Dec 05 18:31:26.594559 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5104:tid 524] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Fri Dec 05 18:31:26.594559 2014] [core:notice] [pid 5104:tid 524] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Fri Dec 05 18:31:26.594559 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5104:tid 524] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4816
[Fri Dec 05 18:31:27.078901 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4816:tid 448] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Fri Dec 12 21:51:38.749809 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5104:tid 524] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Fri Dec 12 21:51:41.796737 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4816:tid 448] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Fri Dec 12 21:51:43.093608 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5104:tid 524] AH00430: Parent: Child process 4816 exited successfully.
[Sat Dec 13 11:24:25.831509 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6184:tid 544] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Dec 13 11:24:25.854544 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6184:tid 544] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Sat Dec 13 11:24:25.854544 2014] [core:notice] [pid 6184:tid 544] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Sat Dec 13 11:24:25.857526 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6184:tid 544] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6680
[Sat Dec 13 11:24:26.865517 2014] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6680:tid 460] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Dec 17 21:24:32.537560 2014] [:error] [pid 6680:tid 948] [client ::1:60268] script 'C:/wamp/www/postin'/register.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://localhost/postin%27/login.php
[Wed Dec 17 22:02:28.555099 2014] [:error] [pid 6680:tid 948] [client ::1:60539] script 'C:/wamp/www/postin'/login.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://localhost/postin%27/home.php
[Wed Dec 17 22:02:52.576181 2014] [:error] [pid 6680:tid 948] [client ::1:60543] script 'C:/wamp/www/postin'/login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Wed Dec 17 22:15:36.019756 2014] [:error] [pid 6680:tid 964] [client ::1:60613] script 'C:/wamp/www/postin'/login.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://localhost/postin%27/home.php
[Sun Dec 21 12:27:45.334508 2014] [:error] [pid 6680:tid 912] [client ::1:59901] script 'C:/wamp/www/postin'/common.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Dec 30 12:18:01.153171 2014] [authz_core:error] [pid 6680:tid 948] [client 192.168.2.5:56561] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp/www/
[Thu Jan 01 18:26:51.143348 2015] [:error] [pid 6680:tid 888] [client ::1:59517] script 'C:/wamp/www/postin'/accountcreated.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sun Jan 04 20:54:45.491787 2015] [:error] [pid 6680:tid 932] [client ::1:57184] script 'C:/wamp/www/postin'/termsofservice.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://localhost/postin'/registerpage.php
[Mon Jan 05 17:24:33.723650 2015] [:error] [pid 6680:tid 964] [client ::1:58637] script 'C:/wamp/www/postin'/login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Mon Jan 05 17:24:37.591476 2015] [:error] [pid 6680:tid 964] [client ::1:58637] script 'C:/wamp/www/postin'/login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Jan 06 22:09:36.379069 2015] [:error] [pid 6680:tid 888] [client ::1:51681] script 'C:/wamp/www/postin'/termsofservice.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://localhost/postin'/registerpage.php
[Thu Jan 08 21:41:11.273540 2015] [:error] [pid 6680:tid 884] [client ::1:62629] script 'C:/wamp/www/postin'/login.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://localhost/postin%27/home.php
[Sun Jan 11 13:29:52.929580 2015] [:error] [pid 6680:tid 884] [client ::1:52843] script 'C:/wamp/www/postin'/profile.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://localhost/postin%27/registerpage.php
[Sun Jan 11 13:41:35.124376 2015] [:error] [pid 6680:tid 952] [client ::1:52970] script 'C:/wamp/www/postin'/login.php' not found or unable to stat
[Sun Jan 11 19:42:59.503446 2015] [:error] [pid 6680:tid 952] [client ::1:53526] script 'C:/wamp/www/postin'/upload.php' not found or unable to stat, referer: http://localhost/postin'/new.php
[Mon Jan 12 18:44:18.786667 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6184:tid 544] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Mon Jan 12 18:44:20.956208 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6680:tid 460] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Mon Jan 12 18:44:34.341014 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6184:tid 544] AH00430: Parent: Child process 6680 exited successfully.
[Mon Jan 12 18:44:52.542886 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8624:tid 536] AH00455: Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Jan 12 18:44:52.542886 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8624:tid 536] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Mar 16 2014 12:42:59
[Mon Jan 12 18:44:52.542886 2015] [core:notice] [pid 8624:tid 536] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\wamp\\bin\\apache\\apache2.4.9\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9'
[Mon Jan 12 18:44:52.545907 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8624:tid 536] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 18300
[Mon Jan 12 18:44:53.289434 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 18300:tid 480] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Mon Jan 12 18:46:01.845526 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8624:tid 536] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Mon Jan 12 18:46:03.846968 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 18300:tid 480] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Mon Jan 12 18:46:03.865961 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8624:tid 536] AH00430: Parent: Child process 18300 exited successfully.
```

Comment: Pressing the `r` key while the Apache Module menu is open appears to just do a restart of Apache. Nothing changes in httpd.conf Anyway, work out if it is Apache or MySQL that is not starting and then look in the appropriate error log for information. That Apache error log you posted does not appear to be showing any errors

Comment: Have you fixed this yet?

Comment: Yes sorry, I just fixed it not to long ago. I could not figure out what went wrong (well actually I figured out that Apache was not working). So to fix it all I re-installed wamp

Answer (score 0):

If there is a problem in apache starting first change the port number from 80 to 8080 and change in httpd.conf form localhost 80 to localhost 8080.

If it doesn't work
open cmd:
Then go to wamp->bin->apache->apache.*.*(version)->bin
execute:httpd.conf -r warn

and restart wamp

Comment: I found it as httpd.exe instead of httpd.conf. Is this the file you refer to?